# I want to restrict " ' [] \ from taking input in html textarea

Tags: html

I want to restrict `"'[]\` from taking input in HTML `<textarea>`. My code is here:

```html
<textarea rows="5" id="comment" maxlength='500'
  onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[$&*%^#!~`(){}:;<>?|,=+-]/g, '')"
  placeholder="Enter your query.">
</textarea>
```

Comment: `id="comment"` … are you writing a comment system that doesn't let people use punctuation?! (In general you are better off using proper escaping rather than trying to limit what characters people send you).

Answer (score 0):

As in you want to replace them as well?

In that case just add them into the character set. You just have to escape each of them with `\` first:

```
/[$&*%\^#!~`(){}:;<>?|,=+\-\"\'\[\]\\]/g
```

I added `\` for a few others as well, such as `^` and `-`, since they take on special meaning within the square brackets.

---

**Edit:** There seems to be problems with the various parsers in reading the regex straight from HTML. Same goes even in JavaScript with the regex in literal form. But I have found a solution. While Stack Snippets and jsfiddle both complain when I do the following, the following works with [Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VaqRdj):

Here's the code:

HTML:

```
<textarea rows="5" id="comment" maxlength='500' placeholder="Enter your query."></textarea>
```

JS:

```
document.querySelector('textarea').addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  var re = new RegExp(/[\[\]\\\'\"]/, 'g');
  this.value = this.value.replace(re, '');
});
```

Comment: I just want to restrict " ", ' ' , \ and [ ] . Other special characters has been successfully prevented.

Comment: @mohanachoudhuri updated my solution. I had to shift some code over to JavaScript, but it should give you what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape any character which is used in RegEx. Here [] are used specify expression. You will have to use some thing like this

```html
<textarea  rows="5" id="comment" maxlength='500'
                onkeyup="this.value = this.value.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '')"
                    placeholder="Enter your query." ></textarea>
```

Comment: Thank you, it prevents the [] braces. Should I write quotes like this ["] to prevent it?

Comment: Not sure If I understand your question. You can add as many characters you want inside the square bracket. But if the character is used in regEx then you just need to escape it with backslash(\)

Answer (score 0):

```html
<script>


function myFunction(event) {

    var x = event.which || event.keyCode;
// " ' [] \
  
if(x=="16" || x=="222" || x=="219" || x=="221" || x=="220")
{

   document.getElementById("comment").value="";
   
}
}
</script>

<textarea   id="comment"  onkeyup="myFunction(event)"  ></textarea>
```

You can use this.